# Add elements to textarea by clicking a button

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add text to textarea when user clicks a button. I have used the code bellow :

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', start, false);
  function start(){
    document.getElementById("button0").addEventListener("click", function(){
      addText(this);
    });
    function addText(elem) {
      document.getElementById("transcript").innerHTML += elem.value;
    }
  };
</script>
```

When the users click the button the text added to the textarea but the moment they type using their keyboard they won't be able to add the text using the button anymore.

Comment: is textarea an actual textarea element?

Comment: Please include the HTML this code is meant to run on, in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `.value` not `.innerHTML`.

`.innerHTML` overwrites the markup of the element, not just the text. Since it's a form element you should be manipulating its value only.

```js
document.getElementById("button0").addEventListener("click", function() {
document.getElementById("transcript").value += "huh";
});
```

```css
#transcript {
height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<button id="button0">Click Me</button>

<textarea id="transcript"></textarea>
```

Comment: Oh! Thank you I have missed that